# How much cheaper are pressure fed engines compared to other cycles (e.g. staged combustion, gas generator, electric pump-fed)?

Tags: engines, engine-design, reuse, cost, pressure-fed-engine

It's well known that pressure fed engines are mechanically simpler, and therefore cheaper than pump-fed cycles (although pressure fed has worse performance). However, I haven't found any sources that say how **much** cheaper pressure-fed engines are, compared to staged combustion, gas generator, and electric pump-fed cycles (specifically for a reusable mid-sized launcher, so something that has the payload capacity of a Falcon 9). Compared to staged combustion or gas generator, I would guess that it's substantially cheaper for a reusable vehicle, as the turbopumps require tons of maintenance between flights. However, it gets interesting for electric pump-fed. Anyone has any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your cost metric?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Cost per flight seems to be the most logical one, assuming that all flights boost the same payload up to the same reference orbit. However, I'll admit that I'm not an expert in these matters, so if there's a better one feel free to suggest it.

Comment: Should development costs be included?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Hmm, good point. I'm asking about reusable launch vehicles that would have flown many times, so I guess the development costs would be spread over tons of launches so it wouldn't be significant - for example, the F9 cost 300 million to develop and flew 94 times, so development costs only accounts for around 3 million each flight. I guess it would be a major factor for a startup or something, but I guess just ignore it for now.

Comment: Historically there's a pretty huge difference between the development cost of a pump- and pressure- fed engine.  I'm also confused by this sentence "However, I haven't found any sources that say how much cheaper pump-fed engines are, compared to staged combustion, gas generator, and electric pump-fed cycles"  Did you mean pressure-fed? And one difficulty is that, there aren't really any pressure fed booster engines, at least that I can think of recently.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah, I meant pressure-fed. I'll go fix that.

Comment: Are pressure fed engines really practical for large launchers? OTRAG and Sea Dragon both planned to use them, but this hardly seems typical given the extreme weight of pressure tanks and high pressures of engines meant to work at sea level. IN any case, turbopumps are *really* expensive

Comment: @ikrase Well, I'm not sure about feasibility, but it should be possible. If a bigger rocket is built, the square-cube law will mean that the tank mass gets smaller and smaller in proportion to the propellant mass, so shouldn't pressure fed engines make more and more sense the bigger your rocket gets?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson the rocket will also get chubbier and chubbier.

Comment: Turbopump is rumoured to account for most of the costs of the whole system, so an engine (alone) without it should be cheaper by way more than a half. However, low-performing engine renders everything else (costlier tanks, low payload) more expensive enough to make turbopump-based systems still win economically, as witnessed.

Comment: @Agent_L Huh. Tanks are extremely cheap though, and for a reusable system they can be used over and over again. The only thing is, to make it reusable with any usable payload left, the vehicle would have to be astronomically big, which I suppose would drive costs up by a lot.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson Tanks are extremely cheap for pump-based systems. For pressure-fed they become pricier and - most importantly - heavier. I don't think it can be resolved by scaling, heavy tanks + weak engine = incapable of reaching orbit at all. Reusability is your red herring, ask if your rocket can fly at all, then wonder if it can do it more than once. Look how difficult was to make Electron fly and how weak it is.